# Navigator.InsertAfter = Invalid Operation Exception - XML & VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, invalidoperationexception, xpathnavigator

I've been struggling with this one since yesterday.
I have an XML file like this (snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ern:NewReleaseMessage xmlns:ern="url-1" xmlns:xsi="url-2" xsi:schemaLocation="url-1-again url-1-again/ern-main.xsd" MessageSchemaVersionId="2010/ernm/32" LanguageAndScriptCode="en">
<MessageHeader>
...
...
```

I've managed to remove some stuff by using XmlNamespaceManager, everything works great.
When I try to insert a line of code, I do this:

```
Dim navigator As XPathNavigator = XmlDoc.CreateNavigator()
navigator.MoveToChild("ern:NewReleaseMessage", "url-1")
navigator.MoveToChild("ern:DealList", "url-1")
navigator.MoveToChild("ern:ReleaseDeal", "url-1")
navigator.MoveToChild("ern:Deal", "url-1")
navigator.MoveToChild("ern:DealTerms", "url-1")
navigator.MoveToChild("ern:Usage", "url-1")
navigator.InsertElementAfter(navigator.Prefix, "TakeDown", navigator.LookupNamespace(navigator.Prefix), "true")
'navigator.InsertAfter("<TakeDown>true</TakeDown>")
```

I always get the same error:

> Invalid Operation Exception.  Operation is not valid due to actual
>   position of explorer.

I've tried several things like not using a NameSpaceManager, using InsertAfter, InsertBefore, InsertElementAfter, InsertElementBefore, with and without the first & second URI on the navigator.MoveToChild, adding a new namespace using xsi instead of xmlns.
I've read several times the msdn website and I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

What I need to add is this specific line:

```
<TakeDown>true</TakeDown>
```

Between to nodes, one is called Usage and the other is Territory.

Thanks since now
Bye bye
Gonzalo

**Edit: Forgot to say there are several Usage and Territory Tags, I need to add the same line between all of them, is this related to the problem?.**